# Convergence of $\sum \frac{b_n}{n}$ Where $b_n = 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,....$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I show convergence or divergence of the following sequence?

$$\sum \frac{b_n}{n}$$

Where $b_n = 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,....$

Im not sure how to use any of the standart theorems to show convergence or divergence.

Any attempts to use comparison test, or finding an upper bound failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Combine the runs with the same sign and you have an alternating series. If you can show those terms converge to zero, the series must converge.

Comment: Grouping together the consecutive terms of the same sign, this is: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sum_{k=n(n+1)/2+1}^{(n+1)(n+2)/2}\frac1k.$$ so you want to know something about $$\sum_{k=T_n+1}^{T_{n+1}}\frac1k$$ where $T_n=n(n+1)/2.$

Comment: @aschepler The alternating series test requires the positive sequence to be  decreasing. For example, if $a_{2n}=\frac1{n}$ and $a_{2n-1}=\frac1{2^n}$ then $\sum(-1)^n a_n$ diverges, even though it is an alternating sum of a sequence converging to $0.$

Comment: $\frac{1}{1}>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}>\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}>\ldots$. So the sum can be written as an alternating series of decreasing terms, and so converges.

Comment: Technically, you need an additional theorem to prove that this subsequence of the series is enough, but yes, you can group the consecutive negative and positive elements together and if that converges, the original series converges. @AdamRubinson

Comment: In fact, I think it can be shown to converge at the same rate as $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. As in Thomas’ first comment, this series is $\sum (-1)^n ( H_{T_{n+1}} - H_{T_n} )$ so the absolute value of the general term is asymptotic to $\log(T_{n+1}) -\log(T_n) =\log(1+2/n) \sim 2/n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the correction. I knew that, but what I typed wasn't precise enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is equivalent to whether: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n c_n$$ converges, where $$c_n=\sum_{k=T_{n}+1}^{T_{n+1}}\frac1{k}=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{T_n+j}$$

Where $T_n=1+2+\cdots +n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$

Then $$\begin{align} c_n-c_{n+1}&=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{T_n+j}-\frac1{T_{n+1}+j}\right)-\frac1{T_{n+2}}\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{(T_{n}+j)(T_{n}+n+1+j)}-\frac{2}{(n+2)(n+3)}\end{align} 
$$

Now, $$\frac{n+1}{(T_n+j)(T_n+n+1+j)}\geq \frac{n+1}{T_{n+1}T_{n+2}}=\frac{4}{(n+2)^2(n+3)}$$ for $j\leq n+1,$ so
$$c_{n}-c_{n+1} \geq \frac{4(n+1)}{(n+2)^2(n+3)}-\frac2{(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{2n}{(n+2)^2(n+3)}\geq 0$$

So $c_n$ is a decreasing positive sequence, and $\sum (-1)^nc_n$ converges. (Technically, you need to prove $c_n\to0,$ but this is relatively easy.)

If $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{b_n}n$, we have shown $S_{T_k}$ converges as $k\to\infty.$

But this means your series converges because for each $n,$ there is a $k$ such that $T_k\leq n< T_{k+1},$ and then $S_n$ is between $S_{T_k}$ and $S_{T_{k+1}},$ and as $n\to\infty,$ $k\to\infty.$

---

**Addendum**

More generally:

> **Lemma:** If $a_n$ is a non-zero sequence, and $K_1,K_2,\dots $ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers with $a_{K_i+1},\dots,a_{K_{i+1}}$ of the same sign, then $S_{N}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$ converges as $N\to\infty$ if and only if $S_{K_i}$ converges as $i\to\infty.$

(We definitely don’t need $a_n$ non-zero here, just the language becomes more complicated to allow zero values.)

Note, we don’t need that the sign of $a_n$ switches between $a_{K_{i+1}}$ and $a_{K_{i+1}+1}.$ That is the most useful and interesting case, but what this Lemma is saying is we can combine any finite sets of contiguous terms of the same sign in our sum and have the same convergence question.

The essential proof of the lemma is that if $K_i<n\leq K_{i+1}$ then: $$\min(S_{K_i},S_{K_{i+1}})\leq S_n\leq \max(S_{K_i},S_{K_{i+1}})$$ and the limit of the minimum and maximum converge to the same value.

Answer (score 2):

The $n$-th "run" consists of $n$ elements (numerators of $1$ for odd $n$ and numerators of $-1$ for even $n$). The last element of the $n$-th run has index $n(n+1)/2$, and the first element thus has index $n(n+1)/2 - n+1$

The respective run adds
$$
r_n = \!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{k=n(n+1)/2-n+1}^{n(n+1)/2} \!\!\!\!\!\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}k = (-1)^{n+1} (H_{n(n+1)/2} - H_{n(n-1)/2})
\tag 1$$
to the value $S$ of the series, where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) with $H_0:=0$ and
$$H_n\approx \ln n +\gamma+\frac1{2n}\tag 2$$

The complete sum is then

$$\begin{align}
S &= r_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty r_n \\
&\stackrel{(1)}= H_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} (H_{n(n+1)/2} - H_{n(n-1)/2}) \\
&\stackrel{(2)}\approx 1 - \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n}\left(\ln(n(n+1)/2)-\ln(n(n-1)/2)+\frac1{n(n+1)}-\frac1{n(n-1)} \right) \\
&= 1 - \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n}\left(\ln\frac{n+1}{n-1}  -\frac{2}{n^2-1} \right) \\
&= 1 - \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n}\Bigg(\underbrace{\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)}_{\textstyle\approx 2/(n-1)}  -\frac{2}{n^2-1} \Bigg) \\
\end{align}$$

This is to be understood as a sketch that has to be fleshed out and be made rigorous, but from the last line it should be clear that the series converges.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. do you mind explain how did you go from 2 to 3? Edit: I now see you used a known approximation.

Comment: $(2)$ is a known approximation for Harmonic numbers.  I dropped the higher order terms for brevity. The last two lines are due to $\ln a-\ln b=\ln(a/b)$ and $\ln(1+x)\approx x$ for $|x|$ small.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_k=b_1+b_2+\ldots +b_k.$
Denote $$u_n={2n(2n-1)\over 2}=n(2n-1)\quad  v_n={(2n+1)2n\over 2}=(2n+1)n$$ Then
$$S_{u_n}=n,\qquad S_{v_n}=-1$$
Moreover $S_k$ is decreasing for $u_n\le k\le v_n$ and increasing for $v_n\le k\le u_{n+1}.$
Therefore
$$|S_k|\le n+1,\qquad u_n\le k\le u_{n+1}$$
The condition $k\ge u_n$ implies $n\le \sqrt{2k}$ hence$$|S_k|\le \sqrt{2k}+1$$
We obtain (setting $S_0=0$)
$$\sum_{k=1}^N{b_k\over k}=\sum_{k=1}^N{S_k-S_{k-1}\over k}= \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}{S_k\over k(k+1)}+{S_N\over N} $$
The right hand side is convergent when $N\to \infty.$ So the series is convergent. Moreover we can estimate the rate of convergence
$$\left |\sum_{n=N}^\infty {b_n\over n}\right |\le {12\over \sqrt{N}}$$

Answer (score 0):

See [OEIS A353874](https://oeis.org/A353874) for the decimal expansion of your sum which indicates

> There are n terms in the n-th group $v(n)$, from $1 / ((n^2-n+2)/2)$ up to $1 / ((n^2+n)/2)$.

and

> As $|v(n+1)| < |v(n)|$, this series is convergent according to the alternating series test.

Your sum can also be represented as

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\frac{n\, (n-1)}{2}+1+k}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \left(H_{\frac{n\, (n+1)}{2}}-H_{\frac{n\, (n-1)}{2}}\right)$$

so $v(n)$ can be defined as

$$v(n)=(-1)^{n-1} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\frac{n\, (n-1)}{2}+1+k}=(-1)^{n-1} \left(H_{\frac{n\, (n+1)}{2}}-H_{\frac{n\, (n-1)}{2}}\right)$$